# How to open extension in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have installed two extensions in Visual Studio 2010.

1. Regex Tester
2. Regular Expression Tester Extension

Both extensions installed successfully. I restarted Visual studio. But I don't see them. I couldn't find the way to use them or open them.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the online manual for both extensions located on their respected pages on the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718325.aspx)

[Regex Tester](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16b9d664-d88c-460e-84a5-700ab40ba452):

> This extension added (contains) tool for testing regular expressions
>   in Visual Studio 2010, 2012. Tool simple and easy to use, the
>   processing occurs in a background thread.
>
> You can use the Shift+Alt+R shortcut to show tool or open menu View ->
>   Other Windows -> Regex Tester.

### Hotkeys in tool:

- Run           Ctrl+P
- Autorun     Ctrl+Shift+A - enable/disable this mode
- Save         Ctrl+S
- New tab    Ctrl+T
- Close tab   Ctrl+Shift+W

---

[Regular Expression Tester Extension:](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bf883ae3-188b-43bc-bd29-6235c4195d1f)

### Quick guide

The tool is available from the right-click menu in the code editor or by shortcut Ctrl R, Ctrl X. You can use it in the following ways:

1. Open the Regular Expression Tester without selecting any text in the code editor. You will get an empty window, where you can start creating your regular expression with options. When you select "Insert", a statement like new Regex(@"\s*a\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled) is generated.
2. Select a string containing a regular expression including quotes - e.g. "(a*b)c" - and start the editor. Your expression will be in the regular expression field to test. When you're done, select "Insert" and the string in your code window will be updated.
3. Select a string containing a regular expression and options - e.g. ("(a*b)c" + "d*[^ef]*" | RegexOptions.Compiled) - and start the editor. Your expression will be in the regular expression field to test and the options will be selected. When you're done select "Insert".